# dplyr: how to modify column names based on a pattern?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

consider this simple example:

```
data <- data_frame('data::col1' = c(1,2,3), 'data::col2' = c(1,2,3))
> data
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  `data::col1` `data::col2`
         <dbl>        <dbl>
1            1            1
2            2            2
3            3            3
```

This kind of dataframe is the output one would get by using Apache Pig. Here, I am able to load it using `dplyr`, but as you can see the names of the columns are cumbersome.

How can I use the `tidyverse` suite to get rid of the part before the `::`? Also, assume I have many columns with the pattern `data::mycol` so *an ideal solution needs not typing manually each affected column.*

output expected:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   col1  col2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
```

Thanks!

Comment: ```my_data %>% rename(col1 = `data::col1`, col2 = `data::col2`)```?

Comment: nice trick thanks @Abdou but I dont want a manual solution. Too many columns in my dataframe unfortunately

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, here: `colnames(data) <- gsub("^data::","",colnames(data))`.

Comment: @joran thanks! but is it possible to do so using the `tidyverse`?

Comment: You should use regular expressions.

Comment: @Noobie Probably, I guess. But I can't say that I personally have much interest shoehorning this problem into a specific set of packages.

Comment: You can use `setNames` inline: `data %>% setNames(gsub('^data::', '', names(.)))`

Comment: Probably because you insist on a tidyverse solutions, which in this case isn't any better. Anyway, an alternative: `library(stringr); str_replace(names(dat), 'data::', '')`

Comment: @Noobie OK. But in that case you might have to mention in your question why using `tidyverse` is more desirable than any other methods.

Comment: its more desirable for my sanity. coming from python, it drives me crazy that I have to use 10 different packages to do some stuff on my dataframe :D

Comment: 10 packages to do stuff on your dataframe? Unless you doing some very exotic things, most dataframe manipulation can be done in base R afaik

Comment: I think the answer is that you can't, or at least not easily. `dplyr` and `tidyr` are packages that make it easier to work with `data.frames.` They  provide a user friendly framework to think about and modify them. Ultimately the column names are a `character` `vectors` so they are not really the focus of those packages. The various base R solutions given are the way to go.

Comment: @Noobie you do realise that you are using "10 different packages" when loading tidyverse? It's just a meta package...

Comment: ...the base R solutions would result in you using _fewer_ packages, if that's what you're after.

Comment: *" it drives me crazy that I have to use 10 different packages to do some stuff on my dataframe"* -- `tidyverse` is literally an agglomeration of several packages. Joran's solution uses zero packages. What's the issue?

Comment: @Noobie Well, part of learning R is to know when _not_ to use a package if it is possible to use much simpler solutions. Learning different ways to solve a problem is nice, but this is not one of those cases where you should ditch the base R approach. Maybe you will come to a case in the future where it is _necessary_ or _easier_ to use `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data <- data.frame('data::col1' = c(1,2,3), 'data::col2' = c(1,2,3))
names(data) <- names(data) %>%
  gsub("data..", "", .)
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw your request for a tidyverse solution.

Comment: if you add a `tidyverse` solution. please keep also the `purr` one. its nice

Comment: Isn't this the same as @joran 's in the comments but it uses the `%>%` instead of nesting the functions? What is here from `purrr`?

Comment: @JohnPaul yes, he wrote that answer in while I was creating mine. Our answers are the same.

Comment: This doesn't actually use anything from `purrr`, does it? Just needs pipes from `dplyr` (or magrittr)

Comment: Wouldn't `data %>% setNames(names(data) %>% stringr::str_replace("data..","")) -> data` be more tidyvers-ish?